# Android google map disappears/redraws for a second

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-maps-v2

You might know that the android studio offers a project skeleton for using google maps. This project just contains a single activity and a map fragment. This is my short version of it:

```
public class MapsActivity extends FragmentActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_maps);

        if(savedInstanceState == null){
            getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                    .add(R.id.wrapper, new SupportMapFragment(), "TEST")
                    .commit();
        }
    }
}
```

With this example I see a "redraw" problem. The map itself disappears for a second (just the map but not the whole map fragment because we can still see the map controls) when:

- App is minimized and opened again
- When user moves to another activity and moves back again to the map

[image]

This was captured on a Nexus4 (4.4.4). However I don't see this issue on another phone that has android 4.1.2.

Any ideas what might be wrong? Are there any solutions for this?

---

### Update

Just found out the google maps app itself has this issue. So this must be a problem with the google maps build on android 4.4.4.

Created a bug report: https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=77192&colspec=ID%20Type%20Status%20Owner%20Summary%20Stars